# Getting foreign key error on updation of database in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to establish simple one to many and many to many relationships and inserting records in tables. But whenever I update the db, I get this error -

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Movies_dbo.Producers_ProducerId". The conflict occurred in database "aspnet-MvcApplication1-20140713210255", table "dbo.Producers", column 'ProducerId'.

Here are my model classes -

Movie.cs

```
public class Movie
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string YearOfRelease { get; set; }
    public string Plot { get; set; }
    public string ImgUrl { get; set; }

    public int ProducerId { get; set; }

    public virtual Producer Producer { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MovieReview> Reviews { get; set; }

}
```

Actor.cs

```
public class Actor
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ActorId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    public string DOB { get; set; }
    public string BioData { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Movie> Movies { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "anonymous")]
    public virtual UserProfile ApplicationUser { get; set; }

}
```

Producer.cs

```
public class Producer
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProducerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    public string DOB { get; set; }
    public string BioData { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Movie> Movies { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "anonymous")]
    public virtual UserProfile ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my configuration file -

```
context.Movies.AddOrUpdate(
            p => p.Name,
            new Movie { Name = "Shawshank Redemption", Plot = "Wrongly convicted for the crime he didn't commit, finds redemption and more in the jail.", YearOfRelease = "1994-5-23", Actors = new List<Actor>()},
            new Movie { Name = "Saving Private Ryan", Plot = "Finding a lost war man.", YearOfRelease = "1998-2-11", Actors = new List<Actor>()}
            );
        context.SaveChanges();

        context.Actors.AddOrUpdate(
            p => p.Name,
            new Actor { Name = "Tim Robbins", Sex = "Male" },
            new Actor { Name = "Tom Hanks", Sex = "Male" }
            );
        context.SaveChanges();

        context.Producers.AddOrUpdate(
            p => p.Name,
            new Producer { Name = "Niki Marvin" },
            new Producer { Name = "Steven Spielberg" }
            );
        context.SaveChanges();

        var movie = context.Movies.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Name == "Shawshank Redemption");
        var actor = context.Actors.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name == "Tim Robbins");
        movie.Actors.Add(actor);
        var producer = context.Producers.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Niki Marvin");
        movie.Producer = producer;

        movie = context.Movies.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Name == "Saving Private Ryan");
        actor = context.Actors.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name == "Tom Hanks");
        movie.Actors.Add(actor);
        producer = context.Producers.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Steven Spielberg");
        movie.Producer = producer;

        context.SaveChanges();
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is the insertion of data correct above? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `insert` or `update` a Movie you need to set a valid `ProducerId` which is an existent `ProducerId` in your `Producers` table. If you pass a value which does not exist in the table, then your `insert` or `update` will be unsuccessful due to the fact that the value does not exist in the referenced table.

If a `movie` does not have to have a `producer`, then you can set the `ProducerId` of your `Movies` table/model to be `nullable` both in the `database scheme` and your `Movie` model.

Comment: According to the model, a movie must have a producer field. So, I can't make it as nullable. In my seed method, I am inserting producer for each movie above, so I am not sure why am I getting this error. I am guessing the problem is with my seed code, but not sure what.

Comment: Does the ProducerId you try to use exist as ProducerId in your Producers table? What is the problematic value?

Comment: I got the hint from your answer, and modified the Movies insertion code to add ProducerId field too. Also, now I am creating Producers list first and then using its Id while creating Movies list. Then I am saving the changes to db. Thanks!